# Tests are not available in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, nerddinner

I'm working through the Nerd Dinner ASP.NET MVC tutorial and am at the part right after I've created the project and am trying to run my unit tests for the first time.  I see the test project and the AccountControllerTest.cs and HomeControllerTest.cs files that were generated but when I click on Test -> Run all options are greyed out.  When I try the keyboard shortcut for tests I get a message that that key combination is bound to command (RunTestsInCurrentContext) which is not currently available.  I'm running VS 2008 Development Edition.

Comment: I got it working later, not sure why it was greyed out at the time I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont think they are available in VS 2008 Development Edition, you need Professional Edition

Look at Code Quality Tools section in the pdf on this link - [Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Express Edition? IF so the tests are not supported

Answer (score 0):

I have the standard edition and built in tests are not supported so I use Nunit.
http://nunit.com/index.php